# Create new columns based on a key column and a value column

Tags: python, pandas

I have two columns keys and of values (legacy bad design inherited), I want to break this columns into multiple other columns depending on the key column and using the value as the value in the row.

```
| Key                         | Value                       |
|-----------------------------|-----------------------------|
| .                           | None                        |
| Review Required?            | Yes                         |
| Installed?                  | No                          |
| Required Publish?           | No                          |
| Published?                  | Yes                         |
| Published?                  | No                          |
| Consult Required?           | Yes                         |
| IS Catalog Reference        | Null                        |
| License Review Required?    | No                          |
```

I tried something like this but it didn't work

```
  df.loc[~df['Key'].isnull()]
 .apply(lambda cols: pd.DataFrame({cols['Key']:cols['Value']},index=[1]),axis=0)
```

A sample on what I wish as a result:

```
| Review Required? | Installed?  | Required Publish? | Published?   | Published?  |
|------------------|-------------|-------------------|--------------|-------------|
|  Yes             | None        | None              | None         | None        |
| None             |          No | None              | None         | None        |
| None             | None        |  No               | None         | None        |
| None             | None        | None              |          Yes | None        |
| None             | None        | None              | None         |          No |
```

This happens a lot of times and not only for yes or no.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) for remove rows with missing values, add `Key` to index and reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.dropna(subset=['Key']).set_index('Key', append=True)['Value'].unstack()
```

Comment: jezrael was quite slow this time, normally it is under 1min ;)